# What type of pronouns are "other" and "another"?

Tags: indefinite-pronouns

When used as pronouns, are "other" and "another" classified as indefinite pronouns?

Comment: _Another_ is indefinite; _the other_ is definite. _Other_, anarthrous, can be either definite or indefinite. Definiteness in pronouns is not really an important feature; that's more for noun phrases. Pronouns just point to noun phrases for the most part, and it's the noun phrases that can be definite or indefinite. _Other_ is originally -- etymologically -- a comparative form; the ultimate root is [PIE *al-](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=al-) 'beyond'. It's only secondarily a pronoun -- mostly it's a determiner.

Comment: If "other" can be a definite pronoun, what would be its type? It doesn't seem to fit the category of "demonstrative pronoun".

Comment: Also, here is a related question:  is the following an example of "other" as a pronoun or a nominal adjective - "It should be on one side of the road or the other."

Comment: They are **not** used as pronouns. "Other" is a common noun. It differs from a pronoun in that it can take determiners such as "this"  and "the", cf, "She left six pears: this one is riper than the others". It is like prototypical nouns in having an inflectional contrast between singular "other" and plural "others", as that example shows.

Answer (score 2):

"Other" and "another" are not pronouns despite what some dictionaries may say.

"Other" is a **common noun**. It differs from a pronoun in that it can take determiners such as "this" and "the", cf. *She left six pears: this one is riper than the others*, ("the others" being a fused-head NP).  It is like prototypical nouns in having an inflectional contrast between singular "other" and plural "others", as that example shows.

"Another" is a alternative-additive **determinative**, either with a following noun as in *May I have another beer, please*, or in a fused determiner-head NP, as in *Ed supports one team and I support another*, where "another" is interpreted as "another team".

Comment: "Other" is not just classified as an indefinite pronoun by dictionaries. There are a number of references that list it as an indefinite pronoun, which suggests there are differences in how this is classified.

Comment: As for "another" I agree that in the form "another beer" is a determinative form, but here also it is less clear that that there is general agreement that it is not a pronoun.

Comment: @tangosquared My answer gives compelling reasons for the classification of "other" and "another" as common noun and determinative respectively. It is based on modern scholarly grammar.

Comment: Hmm. If *others* is a common noun, how can *the others* be a fused determiner-head NP?

Comment: I didn't say that "the others" is a fused determiner-head NP, but just a fused-head NP (or more precisely a fused modifier-head NP).

Comment: Oops. Quite right. So in "the other people" is *other* a noun in modifier function? It seems a bit odd to me, because it's fairly unusual for a plural noun to be in modifier function within a regular NP. And, of course, *the other**s** people* wouldn't be possible ...

Comment: But then I remember being perplexed by CaGEL's analysis of *other* before ...